# Start many processes using systemd ansible

Tags: ansible

I want to start N processes with the [`systemd`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/systemd_module.html) module, let's suppose I have the following service:

```sh
# file: /etc/systemd/system/sleep@.service
[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sleep 420

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I want to start 3 processes with the systemd module:

```
- name: Start Systemd Unit
  systemd:
    name: 'sleep@{1..3}.service'
    state: 'started'
```

The task above creates only **one encoded** process `sleep@\\x7b1..3\\x7d.service`, I can't figure out how to not encode the string. Does ansible support creating multiple processes? if not, what is the easiest way to do so?

---

My current workaround defines a list of services that have an `instances` key, using the `subelements` I'm able to create those processes separately. I think there is a better way to it.

```
app_systemd_services:
  - name: sleep
    instances: "{{ range(3) | list }}"
```

```
- name: Ensure Systemd Units are started
  systemd:
    name: "{{ item.0.name }}@{{ item.1 }}.service"
    state: started
  loop: "{{ app_systemd_services | subelements('instances') }}"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ansible does not support ranges (...). Use `with_items`.

```
- name: Start Systemd Unit
  systemd:
    name: 'sleep@{{ item }}.service'
    state: started
  with_items:
    - 1
    - 2
    - 3
```

One more unsolicited advice. If you use templates for systemd, use `.target` unit with dependency.

Template for `foo@.service` should say `Wanted-by: foo.target`, and than you can manage them by `systemctl stop/start/restart foo.target`.

Comment: [`range`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-sequence) is supported, my example works perfectly and allows me to create a list of services, each one with many instances. I think that the `Target unit` is the best solution, I can have more control over the services, thanks.

Comment: I meant three dots syntax (...), not a `range` filter.

Comment: Nowadays, `loop` is recommended over `with_items`: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#comparing-loop-and-with